# Thrift random crashes on SSL_accept

Tags: c++, openssl, thrift

I'm developing a client and a Threaded server in C++ but I'm facing problems with OpenSSL/TLS integration.

So far, I've followed the ThriftServer.cpp and ThriftClient.cpp but I'm getting random errors which cause the crash of my application.
Specifically, the crash happens when a client tries to call the defined thrift interface on the server (already live)

```
/* server init with PEM public/private certificates 
 * and trusted certificates, socketFactory->accept(true),  
 * transport->open() */

myServer->start();  //running on separated thread, calling thriftserver->serve();

/* client init with PEM public/private certificates 
 * and trusted certificates, socketFactory->accept(true),  
 * transport->open() */

myClient->beginSession(); //Thrift API call - crash
```

The crashes are really generic: sometimes it gives me

```
TConnectedClient died: SSL_accept: error 0
```

and sometimes

```
TConnectedClient died: SSL_accept: parse tlsext
```

and both ending with SIGSEV.

I am running a Debian 8.1 x64 with latest OpenSSL 1.0.2d compiled from sources and flag *enable-tlsext*, thrift from github/trunk and libevent from github/trunk.

I've tried my custom self-signed certificates and the testing certificates shipped with Thrift: in both cases it doesn't work, but they are working with *openssl s_client* and *openssl s_server*

Any idea about the cause of these errors?

**EDIT**

I've compiled OpenSSL with Thread support (threads flag on ./configure) and now my application triggers always the error

```
SSL_shutdown: broken pipe
```

when the client tries to contact the server. Digging more in details, the openssl s_client triggers a

```
sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

using TLSv1.2 as protocol. I've checked [this other Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113039/ssl23-get-server-hellosslv3-alert-handshake-failure) question but it didn't help, as long as I'm using the latest OpenSSL snapshot already

Comment: *"Any idea about the cause of these errors?"* -  did you install OpenSSL's multi-threaded locks?

Comment: Hi, I had the 'SSL_shutdown: broken pipe' error, try to call transport->close() in the client when the call is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the SSL_shutdown problem, according to this [document](https://thrift.apache.org/lib/cpp), you are supposed ignore the SIGPIPE signal to avoid server crashes:

> SIGPIPE signal
>
> Applications running OpenSSL over network connections may crash if SIGPIPE is not ignored. This happens when they receive a connection reset by remote peer exception, which somehow triggers a SIGPIPE signal. If not handled, this signal would kill the application.

This can be done with:

```
#include <csignal>
// ...
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though I'm not have to work with OpenSSL + thrift for the moment, probably the new OpenSSL 1.1.x fixed this, but I haven't tested it.