# SSH error during git pull

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I'm trying to run `git pull` on my Windows machine and get this error:

```
fatal: unable to access '(address_here)': 
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

How could I avoid it?

Comment: Are you sure you can access your Git repository?  Is it offline?

Comment: Sure. I have an web interface and it allows me to browse the repository.

Comment: The browser isn't going over SSH, which is your error. Can you SSH to the host?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL23\_GET\_SERVER\_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31113039/ssl23-get-server-hellosslv3-alert-handshake-failure)

Comment: @DonBranson How to check ssh on windows machine?

Comment: `ssh <target host>` from a command prompt.

Comment: yeah, I get `ssh: connect to host <address here> port 22: Bad file number`

Comment: Google tells me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an https error, not an ssh error: double-check the value of

```
git remote -v
```

Try also:

- the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) you can find, like [`PortableGit-2.15.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.15.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.15.0-64-bit.7z.exe) (unzip it anywhere you want, no setup)
- then in a `CMD` session, set your `PATH` with:

  ```
  set G=c:\path\to\latest\git
  set PATH=%G%\bin;%G%\usr\bin;%G%\mingw64\bin
  set PATH=%PATH%;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
  ```
- set your `HOME` in that same `CMD` session

  ```
  set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
  ```
- Finally, still from that same CMD (with its simplified PATH), cd to your Git local repo, and try your `git pull` again.

That would be enough to make sure you are using the latest openSSL.

And that would eliminate any interference from your current `%PATH%`.

Comment: @Alexander If this has worked, I suspect your PATH must include a reference to an old OpenSSL before including the Git PATH (which has an up-to-date OpenSSL library)